# What happens if array data isn't present when inserting data at a particular index?

Tags: objective-c

Given this code:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
[arr insertObject:@"abc" atIndex:4];
```

What happens?

Also:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray  alloc]initWithObject:@"a",@"c",@"d"];
[arr insertObject:@"b" atIndex:1];
```

How does insertion work?  Does it delete that element and insert?

Comment: Er, why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: i dont now how insert work

Comment: so tell me how can insert element in array i am trying but not done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject%3aatIndex%3a) on `index`:

> The index in the array at which to insert `anObject`. This value must not be greater than the count of elements in the array. Important: Raises an `NSRangeException` if index is greater than the number of elements in the array.

So, in your first example, you'll get a range exception since 4 > 0.

Continuing…

> If `index` is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.

In your second example, c and d will be shifted over, so your array will be "a, b, c, d".

In the future, please check the documentation / try first before posting a question.

Comment: i know that but i am try second example but they give me error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: is program is correct if yes sowhen  i am trying on http://www.compileonline.com/ and they give me an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSLog (@"hello world");
   NSMutableArray *arr;
   arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"c",@"d"];
   [arr insertObject:@"b" atIndex:1];
   NSLog(@"Array %@",arr);
   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}